# Set value of NSTextField

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I am trying to set the value of an `NSTextField`, but it's not working properly.

I have a button linked to an `IBAction`, and when I set it using `self`, it works fine:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface TestMessage : NSObject {
     IBOutlet NSTextField *text;
}

- (IBAction) setMessage: (id) controller;
- (void) Message:(NSString *) myMessage;    
@end
```

---

```
#import "TestMessage.h"

@implementation TestMessage

- (IBAction) setMessage: (id) controller {
    // This works
    [self Message:@"Hello"];

    // but this doesn't
    TestMessage * messageTest= [TestMessage new];
    [messageTest Message:@"Hi"];

}
- (void) Message: (NSString *) myMessage {
    [text setStringValue: myMessage]; 
    NSLog(@"Message Was Called");
    // This returns <NSTextField: 0x1001355b0> when called 
    // using self, but null when called the other way.
    NSLog(@"%@", text);
}

@end
```

I've searched for a while, but still can't find the answer.

I guess it has something to do with the delegate, but I'm not sure.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you setting up the function in the init and didLoad methods? Could we see the .h file?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure message is called when you call it from `anotherFuntion`? If `anotherFuntion` is a method of another class, calling `[self message:]` won't work as you expected to...

Comment: Yeah. I used NSLog to make sure its being called and it is, but just not changing the value of the text field. If it goes IBAction -> Message, it works, but not IBAction -> anotherFunction -> message.

Comment: May you post your XCode project?

Comment: I just tried to make a test App to show you, but it worked fine. It's probably something else that's causing it. I'll post back if I find anything.

Comment: I found the real problem, and updated my question. and I'm sure the function is being called in both scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I have been fiddling with the same issue today. 
You have to return string value in textfield:

```
[textField stringValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
TestMessage * messageTest = [TestMessage new];
```

is unusual, specifically `new`. I'm going to assume that `new` is just a class method does normal `alloc`/`init` equivalent to

```
 TestMessage * messageTest = [[TestMessage alloc] init];
```

The main problem is that `IBOutlet NSTextField *text` will be initialized only if the class `TestMessage` is loaded with a Nib file. It would have to be named as the class of an object in Interface Builder, like so

[image: Set to load this class in IB]

and you would have to implement `initWithCoder` and `encodeWithCoder` something like this in order to extract your field value from the IB encoding:

```
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self) {
        self.text = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"text"];
    }
    return self;
}


-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    [super encodeWithCoder:coder];
    [coder encodeObject:self.text forKey:@"text"];
}
```

Fundamentally, `IBOutlet` fields do not get wired up wherever you create an instance of that class. If they did, how would you express that field A should be wired to UI object A and field B should be wired to UI object B? The connection is established only in the context of loading a class from a Nib file.